# What does being reported to the CRS entail?

Tags: united-kingdom, italy, common-reporting-standard

I moved a few years ago from Italy to the UK. Recently, my Italian bank has sent me an email saying that they were going to report me to the CRS.

Do I have to worry about it? What does that change for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about it assuming you're not using your accounts for tax evasion or other illegal purposes and it doesn't change anything about your situation. As explained [here](https://globalbanks.com/meaning-of-crs/) for example, the CRS requires banks to report the details of non-domestic customers:

> CRS is the Common Reporting Standard introduced by the Organization for Economic Co-operation and Development (OECD) to increase financial transparency globally and combat international tax evasion. CRS accomplishes this by requiring financial institutions in participating countries to report non-resident account details to relevant member countries.
> The information that financial institutions collect will be sent to participating countries each year. This information includes personal details, such as a residential address, citizenship, residency, taxpayer identification numbers, date of birth, and place of birth.
> In most cases, financial institutions will only send this information to an individual's country of residence. However, many banks claim they also share information with a person’s country of citizenship (regardless of residency) to make sure all accounts are correctly reported.
> In doing so, the bank is effectively protecting itself from claims that it did not report financial records correctly. But, it also means that non-resident accounts may be reported to a person's country of citizenship for no particular reason.
> Of course, if a person has their residency in order and has correctly followed their country’s requirements for becoming a non-resident, they will have no problem with this. Besides concerns with how their home country uses this information and possible privacy concerns.